# How do i get rst driver version from device manager using powershell

Tags: python-3.x, windows, powershell, shell, automation

I have Powershell script which fetches the driver version of rst vmd controller,The problem is if we
hardcode the name ex: "RST VMD CONTROLLER 467F" in to the script i was able to get the driver version,
but i want the script to just fetch driver details with help of just "Intel RST" keyword.

Is there any keyword like grep or anything to simplify this?
or is there any other way to fetch rst driver version?
or is there anyway to do all this in python.

I tried this script but it was able to do only if i gave full name inside the script.

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver
 | where{$_.DeviceName -like "Intel RST VMD Controller 467F" } | Format-List
```

Comment: tried with above suggestion but no output in shell

Comment: Use `*` not `%` i.e. `where{$_.DeviceName -like "Intel RST*"`

Comment: Working with this method